# Magento 2.4 REST API for Create Cart Not Working

Tags: addtocart, rest-api, quote, magento2.4

I am trying to create the magento default REST API for add simple product to cart like this way.

1. First I generate the customer token with the use of this API Call.
   https://www.domain.com/rest/default/V1/integration/customer/token
   And it will successful return the token.
2. Now with the use of that token, I call another API to added the product to the existing cart like this :
   https://www.domain.com/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/items

   Headers:

   Content-Type: application/json

   Authorization: Bearer "CUSTOMER TOKEN"

And Pass the parameter as POST

```
{
    "sku": "PO-002",
    "qty": 1,
    "quote_id": "4"
}
```

And it always return the **error like this** :

```
{
    "message": "\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.",
    "parameters": {
        "fieldName": "cartItem"
    }
}
```

See the image :

[image]

Can any one help me here?

Comment: @Pawan how can I check this in postmen? I want to pass in body, right?

Comment: please try: {cart_item:{
    "sku": "PO-002",
    "qty": 1,
    "quote_id": "4"
}
}

Comment: in body parameter

Comment: It return error like this : "Server cannot understand Content-Type HTTP header media type text/plain"

Comment: you need to set `raw`+`JSON(application/json)`

Comment: Can you tell me how we can set that on Postmen?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118154/discussion-between-dhiren-vasoya-and-pawan).

Comment: @DhirenVasoya did you got solution for this?. Am facing same issue

Answer (score 2):

Please look at the example in the docs. The item should have a key named cartItem.
Use the body to send a json that looks something like this:

```
{
    cartItem: {
        "sku": "PO-002",
        "qty": 1,
        "quote_id": "4"
    }
}
```